# giving SSL certificate for virtual host laravel

Tags: laravel, ssl, xampp, vhosts

I have a project I want to work as a frontend dev and the backend in laravel 
everything is fine I'll start work, but when I access any page on the website, the links (such as image, css, js etc links) is HTTPS, but the link in my machine is HTTP, so I most have SSL to run the project

**I tried vhost** :

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/bm/public"
    ServerName business.example.lc:8000
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com 

    #   SSL Engine Switch: Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.

    SSLEngine on    
    SSLCertificateFile    "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key/server.key"
  
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/bm/public">
        #SSLOptions +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/bm/public"
    ServerName business.example.lc:443
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com 

    #   SSL Engine Switch: Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.

    SSLEngine on    
    SSLCertificateFile    "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key/server.key"
  
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/bm/public">
        #SSLOptions +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and the **hosts** file

```
127.0.0.1:8000          business.example.lc
```

but it views me 404 when I access to `https://business.example.lc/` it only works on `http://business.example.lc/`

I also tried :

```
> C://xampp/htdocs/bm> makecert.bat
```

but here when I submit, it requires a password :

```
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

returns :

```
C:\xampp\apache>makecert.bat
Generating a RSA private key
..........+++++
....................................................................................................+++++
writing new private key to 'privkey.pem'
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verify failure
7920:error:2807106B:UI routines:UI_process:processing error:crypto\ui\ui_lib.c:545:while reading strings
7920:error:0906406D:PEM routines:PEM_def_callback:problems getting password:crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:59:
7920:error:0907E06F:PEM routines:do_pk8pkey:read key:crypto\pem\pem_pk8.c:83:
unable to load Private Key
5656:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
Can't open server.csr for reading, No such file or directory
8304:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:69:fopen('server.csr','r')
8304:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:76:
Could Not Find C:\xampp\apache\.rnd
Could Not Find C:\xampp\apache\server.csr
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.

-----
Das Zertifikat wurde erstellt.
The certificate was provided.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: First of all, if you are using linux/windows/mac, you don't define `IP:PORT` in your `hosts` file, just the `IP`. Secondly, show us your `.env` (without sensitive information) as maybe you have a wrong `APP_URL` set up... it depends a lot in the project. Share more info with us... Out of the box, there is no HTTPS option, you just work with the protocol you are in... Hope URLs/Protocols are not hardcoded...

Comment: About your last update, when it shows `Enter PEM pass phrase:` and you write and **NOTHING IS WRITTEN**, that is normal, the idea is that you write but no `*****` is going to show up, so no one can see/understand/try to guess what you are writing, that is normal for any OS... So write the passphrase you want, and then it will ask you to write it again, and do so, do not expect to see `*********` meanwhile you write it.

Comment: thank you, I deleted the port from the hosts file, and now when I open the http://business.example.lc/ it's opening the xampp dashboard like localhost/dashboard
my `APP_URL` in `.env` is `APP_URL=https://business.example.lc`.
and when I open http://business.example.lc:8000/ or http://127.0.0.1:8000/ opens the landing page of my project

Comment: I am not sure if `XAMPP` will work for you, as it uses port `8000` or `8080` but you need SSL and that only happens in `443`. I don't know the current state of `XAMPP` to help you with that, as I only use `docker` or `apache`/`nginx` out of the box. No more 3rd party web servers.

Comment: I re-updated the question, my app is on PORT `8000`, I can't change it because it came from `>PHP artisan serve`, it's so confusing

Comment: it worked, I accessed the makecert file and its worked